# VS2010 Premium 'Connect To TFS' window not staying open

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, tfs, windows-xp, xp-mode

I have installed and registered Visual Studio 2010 Premium (+SP1) onto the Windows XP Mode VM within Win 7 Pro; I have applied all of the product updates also. I have not yet created any projects as my first task was to try and connect to our TFS 2013 Server.

My problem is that from within Visual Studio 2010 whenever I try to "Connect To Team Foundation Server" from either the Start Page; The 'Team' Menu drop down or the icon in the Team Explorer tab, the window to "Connect To Team Project" flashes up and immediately closes and so I cannot enter the details of my TFS server.

I cannot find any errors 'Event Viewer' and there is no further information from Visual Studio. It cannot be the TFS setup as I haven't got that far yet.

[image: VS2010 Install]

Comment: XP mode was designed to support allocations that would not run on Windows 7. As Visual Studio 2010 does I am dubious of the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this and it is somewhat unbelievable, but it definitely worked for me:

Ensure HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel\Colors = 0
Go to Internet Properties -> General -> Colors
Change the check state of 'Use Windows Colors' and change the check state back again then click OK and click OK on the internet Properties page.

My "Connect To Team Project" window now stays open allowing me to select a server!

A colleague enlightened me to this trick which is regularly used for Win 7 installations but this is the first XP version (although it is the Win7 XP Mode VM).

This works to fix flashing pop up screens for Win7 & XP and has been reported to MS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like XP mode is interfering. Not all applications are supported and I have never seen or used visual studio in this manor.

You would be better either running VS2010 on your local Windows 7 or running it in a VM (Not in XP mode).